# Botão submit dando erro - PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou colocando um formulario no meu index.php, para ser enviado os dados preenchidos para meu e-mail.

Como eu faço para quando a pessoa clicar no botão submit(enviar), a página **não** atualizar?

O sistema está funcionando direitinho, envia para o meu e-mail corretamente, mas quando clico no botão para enviar, aparece isso olha.

[image: FOTO]

Alguém sabe porquê está dando este erro?

index.php

```
<?php
$msg=0;
@$msg= $_REQUEST['msg'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head> etc...

<body>
<form action="processaForm.php" method="post">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label><br>
        <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" required><br>
        <label for="email">E-mail: (obrigatório)</label><br>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required><br>
        <label for="telefone"> Telefone/Whatsapp:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" value="27 " required><br>
        <label for="assunto"> Descreva o serviço que deseja:</label><br>
        <textarea name="assunto" id="mensagens assunto"> </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" id="miniSuccessAnimation" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
</body>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
$para= "lukasdesigner@outlook.com";
$assunto= "Contato pelo Site";
$nome= $_REQUEST['nome'];
$fone= $_REQUEST['telefone'];
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$msg= $_REQUEST['assunto'];

    $corpo = "<strong> Mensagem de Contato</strong><br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong> Nome: </strong> $nome";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Telefone: </strong> $fone";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Email: </strong> $email";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

    $header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";
    $header .="From: $email Reply-to: $email\n";
mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$header);
header("location:index.php?msg=enviado");
?>
```

Comment: Poste seu código, vai nos ajudar a te ajudar.

Comment: pronto, já inseri o código.

Comment: Esse erro é porque o caminho do `<form>` ou do `hader("location:")` provavelmente está errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução não recarregar a página (você precisa do jQuery.js instanciado):

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label><br>
    <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" required><br>
    <label for="email">E-mail: (obrigatório)</label><br>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required><br>
    <label for="telefone"> Telefone/Whatsapp:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" value="27 " required><br>
    <label for="assunto"> Descreva o serviço que deseja:</label><br>
    <textarea name="assunto" id="assunto"> </textarea><br>
    <input type="button" id="miniSuccessAnimation" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#miniSuccessAnimation").click(function () {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "processaForm.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {nome: $("#nome").val(), email: $("#email").val(), telefone: $("#telefone").val(), assunto: $("#assunto").val()}
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });

        request.fail(function () {
            alert("OPS ocorreu um erro na requisição.");
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$para= "lukasdesigner@outlook.com";
$assunto= "Contato pelo Site";
$nome= $_REQUEST['nome'];
$fone= $_REQUEST['telefone'];
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$msg= $_REQUEST['assunto'];

    $corpo = "<strong> Mensagem de Contato</strong><br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong> Nome: </strong> $nome";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Telefone: </strong> $fone";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Email: </strong> $email";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

    $header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";
    $header .="From: $email Reply-to: $email\n";
    if(mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$header)){
        echo "E-Mail enviado";
    }else{
        echo "E-Mail não enviado";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Ei, guilherme. Por eu ter colocado header("location:index.php?msg=enviado"); no meu php, a página está sendo atualizada do mesmo jeito. e se eu tiro isso, quando eu clico pra enviar, a página fica em branco.

Comment: Você substituiu seu código exatamente como eu coloquei acima?
Incluiu o jQuery nos header?
Quando você clica no botão aparece alguma mensagem alert() na tela?

Comment: Eu já tinha o jquery anexado na pagina, pq uso outros JS. 
Nao apareceu um alert, abriu uma pagina toda branca escrita "email enviado".
Vale lembrar que, eu já coloquei uma "animação" quando clica no botão enviar. Abre um pop-up na lateral, vou atualizar o post pra vc ver a foto

Comment: Como eu já coloquei isso, não preciso que apareça nada na tela, preciso apenas que ela não atualize, para o pop-up aparecer e conseguir ser visualizado

Comment: Então tem algo errado, pois o script que coloquei tirei o action do form pois a página não pode ser atualizada... acho que você esqueceu de copiar algo amigo... Quando você clicasse no botão caso o e-mail fosse enviado um alert com a mensagem de sucesso apareceria, caso contrario erro...

Comment: é, coloquei exatamente como está e não funcionou, vai pra uma nova página toda em branco, com a mensagem "E-Mail enviado"

Comment: Tem como você editar o código colocando para não aparecer nenhum alert? apenas não atualizar a página quando clica no botão, sendo enviado ou não.

Comment: Então, se não quer o alert é so apaga-lo, mas pelo que me disse a página ainda recarrega... estou confuso pois testei aqui e não está carregando a página...

Comment: este if else que vc colocou no php, seria para quê? é isto que tá fazendo abrir uma nova pagina com o texto "email enviado"

Comment: Se a função MAIL conseguir enviar o e-mail ele mostra "E-Mail enviado" caso contrário ele mostra a outra mensagem.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68903/discussion-between-guilherme-biancardi-and-lukas-monteiro).